# No output sound on LG Gram 2023 i7-1360p

Tags: sound, alsa, pipewire

I recently bought the lg gram 2023 and I have the output sound problem, even though I have tried many methods from [this](https://knowledgebase.frame.work/ubuntu-audio-issues-Bkw2Wlf2o) website. I'm pretty sure that the speaker working just fine when I'm using Windows, but since I've switched to Ubuntu 23.04, there is no sound output. if I use a headphone or bluetooth devices, i could hear the sound fine but the laptop's speaker doesn't seem working. Please help!

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 uses Pipewire instead of Pulseaudio, so I've edited the tags for you. Does your sound device show up in the settings?

Comment: Yes it does, and I also enable pipewire as instructed from this https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e?permalink_comment_id=4508776

Comment: in 23.04, you don't need to enable it. It's enabled by default. Can you add a screenshot of your sound settings when the speaker is selected?

Comment: I seem to have the same issue Did you make any progress getting it resolved?